# How to use the “tilt” feature on an iphone with CoreMotion framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion

I found how to use tilt with UIAccelerometer , but is deprecated .

I want to make an app that when the user tilt down to change the image .
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I think this maybe what your looking for

[How to replace uiaccelerometer with cmmotionmanger][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340384/how-to-replace-uiaccelerometer-with-cmmotionmanager

Comment: CoreMotion might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646433/measuring-tilt-angle-with-cmmotionmanager or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379830/ios-core-motion-detect-forard-backward-tilt